# While loop to repeat actionPerformed of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, do-while

I've got a `JFrame` with some `JButtons`. The "update" button (named `JButton1`) executes a number of queries which fill a form.
Now I'd like another `JButton` to be the "automatic update" (named `JButton2`), so I would like it to loop inside the `JButton1ActionPerformed` method, until `JButton2` is no longer selected.
When I press `JButton2` the window freezes.

Is my code right? Do you think I would need a *stop button*?

```
private void jToggleButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       if(jToggleButton2.isSelected()){
           start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            do{
                do{
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
                while(System.currentTimeMillis()-start>3000);

            }
            while(jToggleButton2.isSelected()); 
       }

        if(jToggleButton2.isSelected()){
            jToggleButton2.setSelected(false);
        }


    }
```

Comment: You need SwingWorker for that. You are looping in GUI drawing thread (The EDT) thats why it freezes.

Comment: Could you explain better? Provide some guide etc.

Comment: You should first go trought Oracles tutorials regarding Swing. Im not asking if you did, because if you would, you wouldnt have such issue like you do.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to understand how the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) and how the SwingWorker  is used for long running tasks.

Comment: @Antoniossss I was not aware of the documentation needed, that's why I asked for some guides. BTW the answer you provided did the job. I'll try to learn how SwingWorker works ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: Yes do that, creating new threads is not the way to go, there are better solutions, but still its perfectly valid if you dont mind ulgy and hard to maintain code :) good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets put aside that you should not crete Thread like I will show you (but use `SwingWorker` for example) you need to do something like this:

private void jToggleButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
       if(jToggleButton2.isSelected()){
          new Thread(new Runnable(){

          public void run(){
                  long start = null;
                  do{
                         start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                   }while(jToggleButton2.isSelected() &&jSystem.currentTimeMillis()-start>3000)
          }
          }).start();

    }
```

Im not focusing on if your code is valid or not, its just shows how to run something in background, so you will not freeze your GUI.

Comment: Can we just highlight that Swing is NOT thread safe and calling `jButton1ActionPerformed` outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread could have unexpected consequences - You should also not be checking the state of the UI components outside the EDT as they may return invalid results due to threading issues

Answer (score 2):

Swing is:

- Single threaded; this means that you should not perform any long running or blocking operations within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread
- Not thread safe; this means you should not update the UI or anything the UI might depend on outside of the EDT. It's also risky to try and address UI elements outside the EDT, as the thread model might return false values

Without more context to your problem, I might suggest using a Swing `Timer`.  Two main reasons:

1. The `ActionListener` is called within the context of the EDT, making it safe to update the UI from within in
2. You can specify a delay between updates, which reduces the risk of overloading the EDT which will cause performance issues

For example...

```
private void jToggleButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (jToggleButton2.isSelected()) {
        // You could use an instance field instead and determine
        // if the Timer is already running or not
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!jToggleButton2.isSelected()) {
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    return;
                }
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        // Just want to point out that this doesn't make sense
        // As if the button was selected, you'd still be in
        // your previous loop
        //if (jToggleButton2.isSelected()) {
        //  jToggleButton2.setSelected(false);
        //}
    }
}
```

Another solution might be to use a `SwingWorker`, which provides you with a means to perform long running or blocking operations off the EDT, but which also provides functionality to update the UI safely from within the EDT.

Take a look at:

- [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

for more details